# How to add grit in high notes?

Tags: voice

I've been experimenting with my voice especially at the higher notes to  achieve that "grit/raspy" sound which what lots of rock singers always did. Sometimes I manage to get that "grit" sound but it feels uncomfortable to the point I keep coughing. This is my cover of she's gone

as you can hear there are lots of strain I did to get that "grit" sound but it did not comes out. Haha. Any tricks or tips on how to achieve the grit?

Answer (score 2):

Simple:  you have two choices.  I recommend the first.

First: get a voice teacher.  Learn basic singing and breath control, then learn screech & fry techniques.

Second: do it on your own and damage your vocal cords beyond repair in short order.

Don't mess with your voice.  You can't go to Guitar Center and buy another one.

Comment: I also want to add that many people don't realize that "grit" and other aspirate sounds are heightened via EQ and editing techniques, so people contort their poor voices trying to match a recording.

Comment: @jjmusicnotes  Excellent point

Comment: @jjmusicnotes EQ emphasizes certain frequencies in the context of music, but does not produce grit. You don't need any editing techniques to produce heavy grit. And no, one doesn't need to contort or damage one's voice to sound like great rock singers, just several years of intense and wise training.